# How would you measure the electrostatic field of a celestial body from its surface?

Tags: electrical-engineering, instrumentation

If we need to measure the Electrostatic field of a celestial body due to its interaction with space plasmas, What kind of instruments can be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to measure electric fields directly is called a "[field mill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_mill)".

It uses moving vanes to impose an AC modulation on the field and a differential sensing setup that allows most sources of error to be zeroed out, something like how a chopper-stabilized opamp works.